# MS Excel "if else if" condition

Tags: excel

How to write in en MS Excel the following condition:

```
if b<0 
  then b:=0;
  else
    if b>1
    then b:=1;
    else b:=b;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

I guess `b` it's a cell in Excel so it should be (let's say it's `A1`):

```
=IF(A1<0;0;IF(A1>1;1;A1))
```

You must use [Function IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)

It's one IF inside another IF.

Anyways, note that in Excel, when you type a formula into a cell, the value will be returned in that specific cell.

If `b` is any kind of variable, you cannot change/use variables with normal Excel functions. In that case, you will need to use VBA programming language (not sure if you mean this).