# Microsoft Excel multiple condition

Tags: excel, if-statement, addition

I have an excel table with weight measurments in different timepoints and I want excel to do the following:

D6: cell with current weight
D5: cell initial weight

```
if D6<0,9*D5 return 1
if 0,8*D5<D6<0,9*D5 return 2
if 0,65*D5<D6<0,8*D5 return 4
if 0,65*D5<D6 return 5
othewise return 0
```

Thanks a lot :)

didnt manage to find a solution yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MS Excel "if else if" condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60337515/ms-excel-if-else-if-condition)

Comment: you already wrote your formula, now convert it to excel nested if function or ifs function

Comment: I am not sure how to behave with double conditions that return the same result.,...

Comment: please edit your question and include the data as text which is copiable and show what you expect for a result. use this link to create the table [For Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)